# How to find the Laplace Transform of two (independent) functions multiplied together?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, laplace-transform

How does one find the laplace transform for an equation consisting of two trig functions multiplied together, when it is not possible to use any trig identities? For example, take a function say;

> f(t)=cos(t)*sin(5t)

As far as I am aware, there isn't any trig identity to "convert" such an equation to consist of only one trig function, and to thus be able to do the laplace transform. Or am I missing some fine detail/trick here? Thanks in advance for any help you may provide!

The only other way I can think of is to do the actual integral to find the Laplace transform. So I guess, I should ask if that is the only way it is possible to do as such?

Comment: Have you considered product-to-sum formulas?  For instance, $$\sin(A)\cos(B) = \frac{1}{2} \left[\sin(A+B) + \sin(A-B)\right].$$

Comment: Ah, that no - I haven't yet. I should be able to solve some equations that way.

Though I guess I found my actual answer to lie within the convolution theorem - something I haven't yet been thought (in the math course I am undertaking at the moment).

Thanks for your help nonetheless!